# Scanf printing weird characters after the input

Tags: c, pthreads, scanf

This code takes in input N-file names and generates N-threads, then the main thread writes something and puts it in a buffer for each thread, and each threads writes their buffer content on their own file. Everything works fine but on the file, the input is like this and i don't know why, hope someone can help me, thanks in advance

```
Hello����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
```

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define fflush(stdin) while (getchar() != '\n')

int n_threads;
FILE **source_files;
char **files;
char buffers[128][128];
pthread_mutex_t *ready;
pthread_mutex_t *done;
char buff[256];

void *thread_function(void *);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    long i, j, ret;
    pthread_t tid;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Error: Usage -> prog | file1 ... fileN\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    n_threads = argc - 1;

    files = argv + 1;

    for(i = 0; i < n_threads; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < n_threads; j++) {
            if(strcmp(files[i], files[j]) == 0 && i != j) {
                puts("Strings are equal.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    puts("Strings are different");

    /*buffers = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * n_threads);

    if(buffers == NULL) {
        printf("Malloc error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }*/

    source_files = (FILE **)malloc(sizeof(FILE *) * n_threads);

    if(source_files == NULL) {
        printf("Malloc error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    ready = malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
    done = malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));

    if (ready == NULL || done == NULL) {
        printf("Malloc error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(pthread_mutex_init(ready, NULL) || pthread_mutex_init(done, NULL) || pthread_mutex_lock(ready)) {
        printf("Mutex init error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    for(i = 0; i < n_threads; i++) {
        if(pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_function, (void *) i)) {
            printf("Error while creating thread %ld.\n", i);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    //signal(SIG_INT, printer);
    
    i = 0;  
    
    while(1) {
        if(pthread_mutex_lock(done)) {
            printf("Mutex lock error.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        ret = scanf(" %s", buff);

        if(ret == EOF) {
            printf("Scanf error.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (ret == 0) {
            printf("Non compliant input.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        getchar();

        puts("before strcpy\n");

        strcpy(buffers[i],buff);

        puts("after strcpy\n");

        if(pthread_mutex_unlock(ready)) {
            printf("Mutex unlock error.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        i=(i+1)%n_threads;
    }

}

void *thread_function (void *arg) {
    int fd;
    //FILE *file;

    long me = (long) arg;

    printf("Thread %ld started.\n", me);
    
    puts("before opening file.\n");

    fd = open(files[me], O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, 0666);
    //file = fdopen(fd, "w+");

    puts("after opening file.\n");

    while(1) {
        if(pthread_mutex_lock(ready)) {
            printf("Mutex lock error.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Thread %ld took string %s.\n", me, buffers[me]);

        puts("before fprintf.\n");

        //fprintf(file, "%s", buffers[me]);

        write(fd, buffers[me], 128);

        puts("after fprintf.\n");

        if(pthread_mutex_unlock(done)) {
            printf("Mutex unlock error.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like an unterminated or improperly terminated character buffer bug. Some compilers fill up memory with junk values like `0xDEADBEEF` or `0xF0F0F0F0` to make it clear when you're out of bounds or using uninitialized data, like you appear to be doing here.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using the super low level `write` instead of the `FILE*`-based tools? I think you're getting the write call wrong, as you're dumping out 128 bytes regardless of the length of that string.

Comment: i tried write because fprintf wouldn't write on the file and i don't know why, i could try again maybe

Comment: Remember to pay close attention to the return values of C function calls. Sometimes an error is indicated, but if you ignore it, all kinds of problems can occur. If you get an error, often you have to check `errno` to find out more.

Comment: Tip: Instead of `fprintf` which is for formatting strings, just use [`fputs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputs) if all you want to do is write a single string.

Comment: `scanf(" %s", buff)` should be `scanf(" %255s", buff)` if you want to read a word without risking to write out of bounds.

Comment: i don't know why neither fputs works and also the %255s format doesn't solve the problem, thanks for your advices

Comment: You allocate `source_files` but never fill in the individual elements (and never use it anyway). You allocate `files` but never fill in the individual elements, so they will have random values. When you do: `fd = open(files[me], O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, 0666);` you have UB (undefined behavior). If the `open` doesn't segfault, you are opening a garbage file name, and the `open` may [probably will] return `-1` (which you do _not_ check for).

Comment: For the `open`, you could do: `char ofile[100]; sprintf(ofile,"output_%ld",me); fd = open(ofile, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, 0644); if (fd < 0) { perror(ofile); exit(1); }`

Comment: When you do: `write(fd, buffers[me], 128);` you're telling it to _always_ write 128 bytes, regardless of how many are in the given part of the buffer. The "funny question marks" are binary 0x00 which is what is in `buffers` when you write beyond the end of the filled in data. You want: `write(fd, buffers[me], strlen(buffers[me]));`

Comment: thank you i misunderstood, i thought that the n_bytes in write was a maximum, thanks everyone for your help